# When are IsRoot, IsAbstract & IsLeaf in UML used?

Tags: uml

I came across the following description of `IsRoot`, `IsAbstract` & `IsLeaf` however do not understand when you would used them.

Excerpt from http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/dotnet/archives/0108/clark/index.htm:

> By checking the IsRoot check box, you are restricting the class from inheriting from other classes. Checking IsAbstract restricts the class from being instantiated, and forces clients to instantiate a derived class to access the functionality of the class. Checking IsLeaf indicates that the class is sealed. Sealed classes are noninheritable and help to limit the depth of an inheritance chain.

My understanding

1. IsRoot seems to suggest that it is a superclass
2. IsAbstract seems to suggest it is an abstract class
3. IsLeaf is a class that cannot be inherited but can be instantiated.

Can someone give me a real-world example of a model that uses these? For example I can imagine class such as 'car' that is a superclass and is abstract and beneath it you would have classes such as 'Volvo', 'Chevrolet', etc.

Comment: Is anyone still using formal UML? (other than design sketches)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - You would be surprised especially for architecture be it infrastructure or software. It gets used for business modeling as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `isRoot` no longer exists in UML2. In UML 1 it means (from the specification) :

> isRoot: Specifies whether the GeneralizableElement is a root
>   GeneralizableElement with no ancestors. True indicates that it
>   may not have ancestors, false indicates that it may have ancestors
>   (whether or not it actually has any ancestors at the moment).

- `isAbstract` means that the element is incomplete and cannot be instantiated.

> If true, the Classifier does not provide a complete declaration and can typically not be instantiated. An abstract
>   classifier is intended to be used by other classifiers (e.g., as the target of general metarelationships or generalization
>   relationships). Default value is false.

- `isLeaf` means that you cannot redefine the element, same as `final` in some programming languages.

> Indicates whether it is possible to further redefine a RedefinableElement. If the value is true, then it is not possible to
>   further redefine the RedefinableElement. Default
>   value is false.

Comment: Thanks Xaelis. Can you give me some real world examples of where I could use these?

Comment: Yes @PeanutsMonkey. Forget isRoot, is no longer exist. A vehicle is Abstract, because you can't instantiate it. You don't know its concrete type. Is it a car, a bus, a boat..?
IsLeaf is more a software design choice. Let's say you have a class TrustedUser and you want to prevent any other architect to redefine this class by inheritance. Then you put its isLeaf property as true.

Answer (score 2):

Not real-life examples, but links to some.

1. `isRoot`: I think this is no longer part of UML. That article is from 2004, which was around the time UML 2 came out, and I doubt Visio supported it. It still may not support it.
2. `isAbstract`: it's a good idea to make all superclasses abstract so that you cannot create an instance that is *not* a member of the subclasses. Classes are essentially sets of instances. What does it mean for an instance to be a member of a superset and none of the subsets? It's unclear exactly what the classification of such an instance is, and it may inadvertently change over time. It's also a good idea to make the subclasses `disjoint` (non-overlapping) and `covering` (all known subclasses specified). There's more details and a real-life example of this using Avians in [Lahman's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=KeGgvtOaeCgC&lpg=PT418&dq=lahman%20disjoint%20subsets&pg=PT418#v=onepage&q=lahman%20disjoint%20subsets&f=false).
3. `isLeaf`: essentially keeps people from overriding your code. I can't verify [this quotation](http://www.coderanch.com/t/100413/patterns/represent-final-modifier-UML), but supposedly the [The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245628) says:

   > Being a leaf or being constrained to be a leaf are not fundamental
   >   semantic properties but rather software engineering mechanisms to
   >   control human behavior.

Does that help?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't. It's too vague. Be good to get some real examples in a diagram.

Comment: Have you looked at Lahman's book? He has already put tremendous work into providing a real-world example of (2). I even gave you a link where you can read about it for free. (1) is irrelevant. What is unclear about (3)?

Comment: Jim L - What I am unclear about is when and how you would use it (IsLeaf) in UML.