# UML 2.x: isLeaf vs isReadOnly

Tags: java, uml, constants, modeling

What is the difference between `isLeaf` and `isReadOnly`?

According with https://stackoverflow.com/a/16253663/2656889 and with https://stackoverflow.com/a/18095538/2656889, `isLeft` means the element cannot be redefined and `isReadOnly` means it can only be read.

I'm using Java. If I want to model a `final` attribute aren't these two the same? Modelling `private static final int PI = 3.14` would yield one of (assume underlined):

```
- PI : int = 3.14 {readOnly}
- PI : int = 3.14 {leaf}
```

In the first case, PI cannot be written to so is deemed final.
In the second case, PI is a leaf and cannot be redefined so it is final as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isLeaf` means you can't redefine the element by inheritance `isReadOnly` means you can't change the value. So `isLeaf` is a constraint on design while `isReadOnly` is a runtime constraint. I think there is no real direct equivalent to a `isLeaf` attribute in Java. But on a class `isLeaf` is equivalent to `final`.

Comment: This good answer could be improved: "But on a class isLeaf is equivalent to final". I think you meant "isReadOnly" rather than "isLeaf".

Comment: Hi ASBH, on a class isLeaf is equivalent to final on a Java class: you can't redefined it, you can't inherit from it.